# Custom Event Parameter from GTM not rendering in Custom Metrics GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have created a Tag as a Google Analytics: GA4 Event in GTM that measures Page Load Time following this article: https://www.lovesdata.com/blog/page-load-google-analytics.

My event seems to be created correctly and I can see the expected values flowing into GA via the debug view.

However, when I attempt to create a custom metric, my event parameter is not flowing in as an option. I added more photos of my implementation in the comments....

I feel like there's a missing link somewhere, any help is much appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Nho.png)
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs4Gj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAUbl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGhvU.png)

I have ensured my measurement ID is correct and confirmed the data is flowing into GA via the debug tool. We are getting expected values in the debug...however, the new EVENT PARAMETER that I created is not showing up in custom metrics as an option.